# laravel many to many relationship get data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between between User and Classroom Models

this is the structure:

```
- users
  - id
  - name

- classroom_user
   - classroom_id
   - user_id
   - is_teacher

- classrooms
  - id
  - name
```

this is the relationships:

user model:

```
public function classrooms() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Classroom::class)->withPivot('is_teacher');
}
```

classroom model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('is_teacher');
}

public function teachers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->where('is_teacher','=',1);
}

public function students() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->where('is_teacher','=',0);
}
```

I want to check if current logged in user is a teacher in current classroom or not by obtaining the value of is_teacher column.

currently doing it this way:

```
auth::user()->classrooms->find($classroom->id)->pivot->is_teacher
```

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would just do it like this to avoid issues in case the classroom does not exist:

```
$classroom = auth::user()->classrooms()->find($classroom->id);
if (! $classrooom) {
   // throw/return an error accordingly
} 
$isTeacher = $classrooom->pivot->is_teacher
```

PS: Doing classrooms with parenthesis is extremely important, otherwise you are returning all the classrooms that belong to the user and doing the filtering in the PHP side.

Comment: **currently doing it this way** :he is already getting the data. He wants to know is there **a better way to do this?**

Comment: doing classrooms with parenthesis returns nothing and gives me an error @LuisFernandoMontoya